# Показать доп столбец заполненый по правилу CASE

Tags: sql

Всем доброго времени. Есть такое задание - Показать еще один столбец в таблице сотрудников. Заполните его по следующему правилу CASE - если сотрудник моложе 30 лет, то 0; если сотрудник 30-50 то 1; иначе 2. Есть такая таблица, записей в ней мого

```
    birthdate    firstnme
    ---------------------
    15.09.1955   John
    15.09.1955   Dalores
    17.05.1956   Mike
    21.04.1961   Greg
    11.08.1962   Britney
и тд
```

Такой должен быть примерно результат (проставлены 2 т.к. они старше 50 лет)

```
   birthdate    firstnme   number_birth
    ------------------------------------
    15.09.1955   John       2
    15.09.1955   Dalores    2
    17.05.1956   Mike       2
    21.04.1961   Greg       2
    11.08.1962   Britney    2
```

Вот мой код, он с ошибками, которые я пока не могу увидеть. Помогите пожалуйста знатоки

```
SELECT birthdate, firstnme 
FROM employee 
WHERE CASE 
        WHEN birthdate < 30 THEN '0' 
        WHEN birthdate 30 BETWEEN 50 THEN '1'
        ELSE '2'
        END IN ('0')
```

Comment: birthdate тип какой?

Comment: @InDevX наверное дата

Comment: И прям через точку выводится? Покажите запрос, и проверьте тип birthdate , без наверно

Comment: @InDevX выводиться через точку. А как тип проверить, каким запросом, я просто только недавно начал SQL изучать, еще много не знаю

Comment: Покажите каким запросом выводите, в принципе.. без number_birth

Comment: @select birthdate, firstnme from employee

Comment: `... DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(now(), birthdate)), '%Y')+0 < 30`

Answer (score 1):

Эта вся логика уже в выводе поля должна быть, `WHERE` не нужно. В конкретике могу ошибаться, но примерно так:

```
SELECT birthdate, firstnme,
    CASE 
        WHEN birthdate < 30 THEN '0' 
        WHEN birthdate 30 BETWEEN 50 THEN '1'
        ELSE '2'
        END number_birth
FROM employee
```

Что за `IN` в конце я вообще не понял.

Comment: с логикой разобрался, но поле birthdate по идее в формате даты и таким образом оно не сравнивает - что с этим делать?

Comment: А, ну так сначала нужно возраст ещё вычислить - вычесть из текущей даты `birthdate` и потом взять количество лет из даты. Как именно взять - зависит кажется от конкретного типа sql сервера.